# c++ static initialization chain and shared libraries

Tags: c++, initialization, shared-libraries

I have a simple case of a static initialization chain.

In file Base.h

```
class Base {
public:
    Base() {
       this->next_ = list_;
       list_ = this;
    }

    virtual void
    Init() = 0;

    static void InitAll() {
        Base* cur = list_;
        while(cur) {
             cur->Init();
             cur = cur->next_;
        }
    }

private:
    Base* next_;
    static inline Base* list_;
};
```

In file A.cpp

```
class A: public Base {
public:
     ...
     void Init() override { ... }
};

static A instance_of_a;
```

I have similar files B.cpp, C.cpp, etc.

I would like to make A.cpp, B.cpp, C.cpp, ... into a separate shared library each, is it possible without using dlsym?  Can I put Base into another shared library?

Comment: I would skip static initialization (and globals) alltogether. Just initialize what you need from main and use dependency injection instead. I assume you did hear of the "static initialization order fiasco" did you?

Comment: Yes, you can create shared objects without using dlopen/dlsym. Regarding libBase.so: do you have a `Base.cpp` file? If not, what would libBase.so contain?

Comment: I will have Base.cpp if want to put into a separate shared library. Or it will be some AppController.cpp holding Base::list_. So how to do it without dlsym?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just works: nothing special is required.